# 'last_login' column in customer admin grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have added a column called 'last_login' in customer admin list grid for getting customer last login time.it is working perfect.But while filteing last login time i am getting error page.Here is my code

> Grid.php

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_of_customer')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_unique_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('company')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('restaurant')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('last_login')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('membership_plan_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('admin_verification_status')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mobile_verified')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('confirmation')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('nationality')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('enable_user')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
        $sql = '(SELECT MAX(logout_at) FROM log_customer WHERE log_customer.customer_id = e.entity_id GROUP BY log_customer.customer_id)';
       $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('last_login' => new Zend_Db_Expr($sql)));

        $collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(e.type_of_customer = '0')"));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $item){
            $item->setData('email_conf',$item->getConfirmation()?'Not Verified':'Verified');
        }
        return ;
    }

 $this->addColumn('last_login', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Login'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'last_login',
            'gmtoffset' => true,
            /*'filter'    => false,
            'sort'      => false,*/
        ));
```

Comment: What if you uncomment this 
/*'filter' => false, 'sort' => false,*/
and change to true

Answer (score 0):

//Try with the following code and check.

```
$this->addColumn('last_login',
        array(
            ....
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterLastLogin'),
    ));
```

Or refer this link : http://www.magespider.com/sales-order-grid-is-not-working-when-filtering-using-any-field-in-magento-admin/

Comment: Nothing found in the refer link